# Error while loading the data TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm writing a real-time search functionality to populate the  dropdown from the autocomplete in Angular with RxJS. I'm getting some error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined. I'm using Angular 10. The code is working fine but if user delete the entire search string it throw the below error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (create-request.component.ts:62)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:30)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:46)
> at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next (distinctUntilChanged.js:50)
> at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at DebounceTimeSubscriber.debouncedNext (debounceTime.js:40)
> at AsyncAction.dispatchNext (debounceTime.js:53)
> at AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:51)

**My Code is as below**

**HTML FIle**

```
            <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-label>Affected person</mat-label>
                    <input type="text" id="affectedPerson" formControlName="userName" matInput required [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" >
                      <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
                      <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers" [value]="user.richFirstName +' ' + user.richFamilyName" 
                        (onSelectionChange)="selectUser(user)">
                          <span>{{user.richFirstName}}-{{user.richFamilyName}} ({{user.login}})</span>
                        </mat-option>
                      </ng-container>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('userName').hasError('required')">
                      A name is required
                    </mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
```

**TS File**

```js
this.form.get('userName').valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(this.debounce),distinctUntilChanged(),
   tap(() => {
      this.errorMessage = "";
      this.filteredUsers = [];
      this.isLoading = true;
    }),
      switchMap(value => this.accessRequestService.getPersonList(value)
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => {
            this.isLoading = false
          })
        )
      ),catchError(error => {
        return throwError(error) ;
      })
    )
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data == undefined) {
          this.errorMessage = data['Error'];
          this.filteredUsers = [];
        } else {
          this.errorMessage = "";
          this.filteredUsers = data;
        }
      }, error => {
        this.isLoading = false
        console.log(error);
        this.errorMessage = error.message;
        if(error.error!=undefined)
        alert(error.error.message);
        this.filteredUsers = [];
      });
  }
```

```html
                <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Affected person</mat-label>
                        <input type="text" id="affectedPerson" formControlName="userName" matInput required [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" >
                          <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
                          <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers" [value]="user.richFirstName +' ' + user.richFamilyName" 
                            (onSelectionChange)="selectUser(user)">
                              <span>{{user.richFirstName}}-{{user.richFamilyName}} ({{user.login}})</span>
                            </mat-option>
                          </ng-container>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('userName').hasError('required')">
                          A name is required
                        </mat-error>
                      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It looks like you're not returning an Observable from `switchMap`

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities which we cannot check with the code you posted:
Either

```
this.form.get('userName').valueChanges
```

or

```
  switchMap(value => this.accessRequestService.getPersonList(value)
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.isLoading = false
      })
    )
  ),catchError(error => {
    return throwError(error) ;
  })
```

is null/undefined. Did you actually check line 62 (indicated in the error message) in your components file? I would assume it the service you are using. Could you post that code?

One sidenote: Calling methods from the template is discouraged since it can cause a lot of performance overhead:

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('userName').hasError('required')">
                          A name is required
                        </mat-error>
```

Should be

```
<mat-error *ngIf="userNameFormControl.errors['required']">
                          A name is required
                        </mat-error>
```